# How can I draw my character in different view?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration

I have this dog character and I need to draw the side view of it, can  anyone recommend me a video/online course to learn the technique to draw my characters? I have a few characters that I need their side view.

[image]
[Click here for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5t5i.png)

Comment: Have you tried [searching on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=draw+characters+from+different+angles)?

Comment: You draw the side view the same way you drew the front view. There is no "automated" option to turn what you have to it's side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that difficult, start duplicating the same character you already have:

- Delete the hidden shapes
- Move, scale, transform or flip horizontally the shapes that remain in the side view
- Add the new shapes that will be seen in this view
- Add shadows and details

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks Danielillo I could not anyone more helpful, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If this was done in 3D, you'd simply rotate the character and get any kind of view instantly. However, with a 2D design, every view is hand made, there is no 'click-here-to-apply-side-view' button. You'll do the side view like you did the front view.

Otherwise, the subject is complex and its the kind of thing they teach in art school, which takes years of practice.

However, I am sure there's plenty of very specific front view/side view tutorials on Youtube.